# How to web-scrape data and send them to google sheets

Tags: html, google-sheets, web-scraping

I have a column of URLs:

- naj.sk/obchodne-podmienky/
- https://eshop.sdetmi.com/obchodne-podmienky/
- https://www.bioliek.sk/obchodne-podmienky/
- https://www.lunzo.sk/obchodne-podmienky/

and I would like to scrape specific numbers into another column.
Specifically: To find the word **IČO** and scrape the next 8 numbers aftewards (which is the company ID number).

[HOW IT LOOKS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1knl.png)

EDIT: OK I found this:
B2: =JOIN("|",IMPORTXML(A2,"//a/@href"))
C2: =REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"[0-9]{3}[- ]*[0-9]{3}[- ]*[0-9]{4}")

EDIT2: OK @href won't work of course :-/

Thank you very much for help

Patrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each url is different, for instance in E2

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(index(importxml(D2,"//div[contains(.,'IČO')]"),1,6),"\d{2} \d{3} \d{3}")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for help. I tried to put it in a cell but I got a Formula parse error. Do you, by any chance, have an idea why?

Comment: share your sreadsheet, It could be easier to solve your issue

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xtwp96w9oDhZPhiSSyJwFL6N89JWcdBUj9ahSEyn1TA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: done, each case is particular, you have to look at each source code

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems I have to ask someone to create me a proper scraper to automatize it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic to implement the same:

you can select the element you want to scrap data using `getElementById` or `getElementByClassName` and then extract that data

refer this article for more : https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/

Comment: Python is a bit too much for me.

Comment: what do you want to use then?

Comment: I have no idea. If I knew I wouldn't be asking for help :) .

Comment: you can create a chrome extension using html css and js